# Where can I find an example unzipper using zlib?

Tags: c, zip, zlib

I'm looking for a bare bones simple example C app for unpacking a zip file using zlib. It must support fairly new version of .zip and must have source right down to the zlib calls.

Answer (score 4):

The zlib-bin source package on my system (linux) has some example programs called "minizip" and "miniunzip" which shows just that.

Answer (score 0):

The [zpipe.c](http://www.zlib.net/zpipe.c) example on the zlib.net web site is pretty straight forward. There is also a pretty good [description](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html) of what it does.

Comment: that seems to only do the compression, what I need is the whole zip file decoding and what not