# Text compression in C or C++

Tags: c++, c, compression

Compression text always gives me troubles if I have to do in C or C++ as there no inbuilt library is available by default unlike python and other languages,So I want to know what is the approach to be followed for text compression in these languages.

For an example consider this [text](http://ideone.com/aEKKP),now which algorithm  or method I should be used to compress this text and to get a very short possibly solution?

Comment: As asked (i.e. "very shortest possibly" [sic]) this question's got bugger all to do with actual programming or C/C++... just go find the latest compression algorithm comparison (don't know if it's a good one, but in the style of http://www.maximumcompression.com/data/text.php) - then invoke that algo from your C++ program.  More realistically, libz's good enough for casual use.

Comment: I am looking for a shortest technique for date compression in C or C++,I really don't understand why this is moved to here,hence I posted [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/233/why-my-question-is-migrated-to-stack-overflow).

Comment: fair enough - I know you didn't mean to post here.  It seems (from the linked file) to have little to do with date compression... perhaps a typo and you mean "data"? And you need to be clear about whether you want the "shortest" compressed data, or just simple, concise C/C++ code. For the former, you can checkout some of those little-used algos from the page I linked in my previous comment. For the latter, libz (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332645/where-can-i-find-an-example-unzipper-using-zlib).  Do you need any more help?

Comment: "http: //ideone.com/aEKKP" is a very good compression of the example text. 100+ lines compressed to less than 128 bits ;)

Comment: Just because you want to know how to compress an algorithm doesn't mean its code golf.  He wants to compress text documents in c++.  That's so on-topic here it makes my teeth hurt.

Answer (score 4):

Go download [zlib](http://zlib.net/).  Use the deflate functions.