# i need to make 2 c++ scripts to compress and decompress Strings on tow different platforms windows mobile and PHP server

Tags: php, c++, apache, windows-mobile, cross-compiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find an example unzipper using zlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332645/where-can-i-find-an-example-unzipper-using-zlib)

Those scripts should be with the same algorithm for compression (or deflating) and decompression (or Inflating) Strings ,So i choose to use the zlib Library to handle this issue,
**My question** is how to use **ZLIB** with c++ in details ,**i.e** integrating and deploying on a Linux platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have an answer for this in another post, look for 'C++ cross-platform zlib simplifer-wrapper'...

Comment: i think gzstream seems to be promissing it'll check it if fits and thnx btw

Comment: does any body know how to compile [gzstream.C](http://www.cs.unc.edu/Research/compgeom/gzstream/#inst) , Using gcc or g++ both raise an error gzstream.h no such a file or directory and all in the same path

Comment: well, if you use #include<gzstream.h> then you need to put the header file in the compiler research path, otherwise you need to use #include "gzstream.h" (please nore the '"' instead of the '<' and '>' characters!)

Comment: of course you can also include in your compile line the g++ option of -I. (this i sthe option -I followed by a dot so that the search is done in the current folder)

Comment: this is how I compiled my test app using the contents of gzstream.tgz untared into gzstream folder: g++ test.cpp -o test -I. -Lgzstream -lgzstream -lz

Comment: i have a problems in the compiling of gzstream.C ,  how could it be .C file and there is in line [30] `#include <iostream>` ??
also when i run Makefile alot of errors raised :

./Makefile: line 36: CXX: command not found
./Makefile: line 38: CPPFLAGS: command not found
./Makefile: line 39: LDFLAGS: command not found
./Makefile: line 40: AR: command not found
./Makefile: line 50: default:: command not found
./Makefile: line 52: test:: command not found
 and others.....

this is the Command

`./Makefile GZSTREAM_NAMESPACE=mynsD`

Comment: humm... you don't run a makefile... you need the make tools installed in your system and then the command is just 'make'. This will run make using the Makefile file in your folder...

Comment: WOW, i did not understand the Makefile and make command (if you can help by  brief description) ,Now it works fine Thank you **"Prince"** :D , i cannot vote 4 u :-s

Comment: don't worry about voting, whats important is to help out so hang around this site and help out others with stuff you know ;-) about make tools, search for it on your favorite search engine, there are lots of info on it... basically it replaces all the flags and options you need to add to the compile command line, you have to learn the Makefile syntax, its not easy but necessary for serious programmer... :-) you also have 'auto tools' that will generate a makefile for you... and you also have other systems like CMake that is make compatible... its a big world out there :-D

Comment: mmm , it was a rough 2 weeks of searching ant tying compression and decompression from different platforms (PHP,C#) so i decided to have a script compress and decompress in the same manner and now it's fast powerful and safe :D,i'll hang out with make under Linux but i don't know it it has alternatives on windows ??